How to count from 0 and onward for every new ID?
I constructed the following query and it gives me the following output...
with tb1 as
(
    select  id
        ,row_number() over(order by id)-1 as lag_0
    from id_store
),
tb2 as
(
    select *
        ,lag(lag_0) over(order by id) as lag_1
    from tb1 
),
tb3 as
(
    select *
        ,lag(lag_1) over(order by id) as lag_2
    from tb2
),
tb4 as
(
    select *
        ,lag(lag_2) over(order by id) as lag_3
    from tb3
)
    select *
         ,lag(lag_3) over(order by id) as lag_4
    from tb4




id
lag_0
lag_1
lag_2
lag_3
lag_4




213
0
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL


215
1
0
NULL
NULL
NULL


217
2
1
0
NULL
NULL


313
3
2
1
0
NULL


315
4
3
2
1
0



The desired Output is what I would like. I only added five ids to keeps things simple. I tried a cross join as well but I got some strange results.



id
group_name
ord_num




213
lag_0
0


215
lag_0
1


217
lag_0
2


313
lag_0
3


315
lag_0
4


213
lag_1
NULL


215
lag_1
0


217
lag_1
1


313
lag_1
2


315
lag_1
3


213
lag_2
NULL


215
lag_2
NULL


217
lag_2
0


313
lag_2
1


315
lag_2
2


213
lag_3
NULL


215
lag_3
NULL


217
lag_3
NULL


313
lag_3
0


315
lag_3
1


213
lag_4
NULL


215
lag_4
NULL


217
lag_4
NULL


313
lag_4
NULL


315
lag_4
0




--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table id_store (id Int);
Insert Into id_store 
VALUES (213), (215), (217), (313), (315);

One option could be using recursive CTE to generate rows and prepare data for fetching the expected result.
WITH 
  Recursive tb1 (pass, id, group_name, ord, rn) AS
    ( Select 1, id, 'lag_0' as group_name, 0 as ord, 
             Row_NUmber() Over(Order By id) as rn
      From id_store 
     UNION ALL 
      Select pass + 1, id, Concat('lag_', pass), 
             Case When rn > ord + 1 then ord + 1 End, rn
      From   tb1
      Where  pass < ( Select Count(id) From id_store )
    )
Select id, group_name, rn - 1 - ord as ord_num
From   tb1;

R e s u l t :



id
group_name
ord_num




213
lag_0
0


215
lag_0
1


217
lag_0
2


313
lag_0
3


315
lag_0
4


213
lag_1
null


215
lag_1
0


217
lag_1
1


313
lag_1
2


315
lag_1
3


213
lag_2
null


215
lag_2
null


217
lag_2
0


313
lag_2
1


315
lag_2
2


213
lag_3
null


215
lag_3
null


217
lag_3
null


313
lag_3
0


315
lag_3
1


213
lag_4
null


215
lag_4
null


217
lag_4
null


313
lag_4
null


315
lag_4
0



fiddle
